# Unnesting REPEATED RECORD with "Column name sentiment is ambiguous" - BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to unnest three record arrays in a single table.
entities, words, sentences.

The issue I've encountered is the "sentiment" field is in both "entities" and "sentences" array and therefore, I get the error "Column name sentiment is ambiguous".

[image]

[image]

Comment: just use `entity.sentiment` and `sentence.sentiment` instead. Meantime, most likely, your query is not what you want because it produces product of all records in those three array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `sentiment AS entity_sentiment` with `entity.sentiment AS entity_sentiment` and `sentiment AS sentences_sentiment` with `sentence.sentiment AS sentences_sentiment`

Comment: thank you! I thought I tried that...